# Triggers on change date

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I'm trying to create some triggers in my db.
Now I need to create a trigger that "fire" a procedure when the date have changed. It's a Db for the management of a Bank.

I need some procedure that start at a programmed date. For example, if I want to set an operation of accredit for the 24/05/2014, this procedure starts only when the current date is equal to the specified value.

I have read that there are some "scheduler" that can help me, but I don't know how to use them! (I'm using phpPgAdmin) There's something that I can do without setting some scheduled procedure? Only using a trigger?

this is my (wrong) trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER programmata 
    AFTER INSERT ON transazione 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE trans_programmata();
```

and this is the (wrong) procedure "trans_programmata()"

```
DECLARE
   p bit := 0;
BEGIN
   IF(new.programmata = p)THEN
     PERFORM * FROM aggiorna_conto();
   ELSE 
      IF new.data >= current_date THEN 
          PERFORM * FROM aggiorna_conto();
      END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL;
END;
```

Here is the table "transazione"

```
CREATE TABLE transazione (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    data date NOT NULL,
    tipo bit(1) NOT NULL,
    ammontare numeric(11,2) NOT NULL,
    programmata bit(1) NOT NULL,
    descrizione character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    fk_conto integer NOT NULL,
    fk_utente character(16) NOT NULL,
    fk_categoria character varying(20) NOT NULL
);
```

obviously, this way the trigger only "fires" when the inserted value of "data" is equal to the current date.

Comment: Please define *exactly* when the trigger is supposed to fire.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your clarification!

As I wrote in the post, I specified :

"I need some procedure that start at a programmed date(a date in the future). For example, if I want to set an operation of accredit for the 24/05/2014(when the current date of today is 19/05/2014), this procedure starts only when the current date is equal to the specified value(in this case 24/05/2014, for example)."

Hope this can help!

Comment: the value 'date' in the table 'transazione' was created for this purpose.

So when the current_date is equal to the 'date' of the specified transaction, the trigger fire

Comment: Instead of "AFTER INSERT" I need something like "WHEN the value 'date' of all my row in table 'transazione' is equal to current_date FIRE the procedure 'trans_programmata' "

It's like the db has to check this table after the change of day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html) (or [event triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createeventtrigger.html) in pg 9.3+) only fire on defined **data events**. What you are talking about is a scheduled (time-based) event. There is nothing built into Postgres for that.

I generally use **cron** jobs to schedule jobs like this.

There is also [**pgAgent**](http://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgagent.php), which used to be packaged with pgAdmin. (From pgAdmin v1.9 onwards, pgAgent is shipped as a separate application.)